# Fastest way to simplify numerator and denominator

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Say, I have two sequences. One of them can be a numerator, the second one is a denominator. Both sequences may contain the same variables. What is the fastest algorithm to get rid of duplicated variables in numerator and denominator?

Example: initial sequences.

```
A * B * C * D * O * V
---------------------
B * O * N * A * C
```

Expected result: A, B, C, O should have gone.

```
D * V
-----
N
```

The only idea that I currently have is to create two arrays and using two loops to find and remove matching elements. Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: Do you want to simplify `2/4` to `1/2`, or only `2*1/2*2` to `1/2`?

Comment: Unless this affects performance, I wouldn't worry about finding the fastest way. For arrays of such small sizes, it probably won't matter.

Comment: Consider looking at some standard library containers such as [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) that allows you to check if an element exists quickly. That will give you an O(n log n) algorithm.

Comment: @user202729 the simplest case - the second, remove only identical variables, no need to calculate an actual relation 2*1/2*2 to 1/2

Comment: Is it important to reserve the order? (can `V*D/N` be outputted?)

Comment: @user202729 No, order is not important, consider this as two unsorted arrays, at the end I just want to get unique values from each of them

Comment: Numerically: find the greatest common divisor (google GCD algorithm) and simplify by dividing both the numerator and the denominator with the GCD. Or are you asking symbolically?

Comment: Another question is where do the numerator and denominator come from? Are you parsing a file? Do the values exist in arrays? Knowing may provide insight into what shortcuts could be available.

Comment: Well, @FeiXiang is correct, and I doubt it's possible to get faster than `O(n log n)` (there are `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_multiset` too)

Comment: You need to remove the union of the two sets.

Comment: Sort top and bottom then compare `equal_ranges` - remove the difference.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Both sequences are generated based on smaller pieces, e.g. I have several words "demo", "user", "computer", then I combine them into phrases "demo user", "demo computer", "demo computer user", then compare phrases to each other and find unique word in each of them. I'm looking at it as at an math expression because there are algorithms that allow to get rid of duplicates, but in general, it can be two arrays of some string values.

Comment: But it isn't a math expression, and the standard mathematical solution as given by @ja72 therefore does not apply. Suppose you ask the question you want an answer to?

Comment: @EJP It can apply because I can assign weights to variables, so they can be numerical

Comment: @Anonymous Be clear what exactly you want. Strings don't lend themselves to dividing algorithms naturally, if you have some extra stuff defined on them (or not), say so.

Comment: No, it can't apply, because the solution as given by @ja72 is to divide both by the GCD, and you can't take the GCD of a string. Your question has nothing whatsoever to do with numerators and denominators. Please correct it so it reflects your *actual question.*

Answer (score 3):

You should look at `std::set_interaction`, it can be used to determine common numbers from two sorted collections.

e.g.

```
 std::vector< int > inter;
 std::set_intersection (numerator.begin ( ), numerator.end ( ), 
                        denominator.begin ( ), denominator.end ( ), 
                        std::back_inserter (inter));
```

Now to remove the common numbers in numerator:

```
 if (inter.size() != 0)
 {
   std::vector<int> leftn;
   std::set_difference (numerator.begin ( ), numerator.end ( ), 
   inter.begin ( ), inter.end ( ), std::inserter (leftn, leftn.begin ( )));
   ...
 then do the same for denominator
```

However I think you should first make sure your denominators and numerators are split up into prime numbers before attempting the above to get best result

e.g.

```
  2 * 4               4 
  -----  would yield ---   which obviously could be simplified more
  2 * 2               2

  2 * 2 * 2           2
  ---------   -->    ---
    2 *  2            1
```

but maybe you already did that.

EDIT: sorted collections

Comment: It should be noted that set_intersection requires the source ranges to be sorted, as do the other set operations.

Comment: "split in prime numbers" - that assumes the terms are constants, not variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution sorting numerator and denominator and then comparing *equal ranges*:

```
std::vector<std::string> num = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "O", "V"};
std::vector<std::string> den = {"B", "O", "N", "A", "C"};

// sort to compare equal_ranges
std::sort(std::begin(num), std::end(num));
std::sort(std::begin(den), std::end(den));

decltype(std::equal_range(std::begin(num), std::end(num), "")) num_er{std::begin(num), std::begin(num)};
decltype(std::equal_range(std::begin(den), std::end(den), "")) den_er{std::begin(den), std::begin(den)};

while(num_er.second != std::end(num) && den_er.second != std::end(den))
{
    // next value to check (numerator or denominator?)
    auto v = num_er.second;
    if(*den_er.second < *v)
        v = den_er.second;

    // find the equal ranges
    num_er = std::equal_range(num_er.second, std::end(num), *v);
    den_er = std::equal_range(den_er.second, std::end(den), *v);

    // count the number of this value for num and den
    auto num_size = std::distance(num_er.first, num_er.second);
    auto den_size = std::distance(den_er.first, den_er.second);

    // erase from either num or den (or both)

    if(num_size >= den_size)
        num_er.second = num.erase(num_er.second - den_size, num_er.second);

    if(den_size >= num_size)
        den_er.second = den.erase(den_er.second - num_size, den_er.second);
}

for(auto const& s: num)
    std::cout << s << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
std::cout << "-------------------" << '\n';
for(auto const& s: den)
    std::cout << s << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

**Output:**

```
D V 
-------------------
N
```